Error: The injectable 'PlatformLoaction' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler's is not available
I was updating my Angular version from 10 to 15 and encountered an error while running the application..
Ideally, the Library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server', or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping
I tried to change the package.json and also checked that all imports are present as per the requirements, but I still encountered this error.
